# How to check a string contains only digits and one occurrence of a decimal point?

Tags: java, regex, string, decimal

My idea is something like this but I dont know the correct code

```
if (mystring.matches("[0-9.]+")){
  //do something here
}else{
  //do something here
}
```

I think I'm almost there. The only problem is multiple decimal points can be present in the string. I did look for this answer but I couldn't find how.

Comment: Doesn't Java have some generic "count" or "count if" type function that works with any type of sequence?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use regex for this? Particularly the way you are doing it, `String.indexOf` would be faster.

Comment: indexOf won't tell you if it's a number ;-)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to -> ***make sure it's a number AND has only one decimal*** <- try this RegEx instead:

```
if(mystring.matches("^[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*$")) {
    // Do something
}
else {
    // Do something else
}
```

This RegEx states:

1. The ^ means the string must start with this.
2. Followed by ***none*** or more digits (The * does this).
3. Optionally have a single decimal (The ? does this).
4. Follow by ***none*** or more digits (The * does this).
5. And the $ means it must end with this.

Note that bullet point #2 is to catch someone entering ".02" for example.

If that is not valid make the RegEx: `"^[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*$"`

- Only difference is a + sign. This will force the decimal to be preceded with a digit: 0.02

Comment: Edge case: ".02" is a fairly common way for non-programmers to write 0 <n<1. (And OP appears to implicitly be ignoring signed figures)

Comment: Presuming that "." or "' are valid but weird zeroes, that works :-) … perhaps rather `^([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)$` to be paranoid.

Comment: Very nice explanation of the regex. You don't often see people explain it.

Answer (score 2):

I think using regexes complicates the answer. A simpler approach is to use `indexOf()` and `substring()`:

```
int index = mystring.indexOf(".");
if(index != -1) {
    // Contains a decimal point
    if (mystring.substring(index + 1).indexOf(".") == -1) {
        // Contains only one decimal points
    } else {
        // Contains more than one decimal point 
    }
}
else {
    // Contains no decimal points 
}
```

Comment: From this how would I add an "if" to check for numbers?

Comment: Very helpful answer!.. one correction..     if(mystring.substring(index+1).indexOf(...)) to get the logic right

Comment: @KurinchiMalar correction made. However, as the other comment states, I don't check the string for digits.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if a number (positive) has one dot and if you want to use regex, you must escape the dot, because the dot means "any char" :-)

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

```
Predefined character classes
.   Any character (may or may not match line terminators)
\d  A digit: [0-9]
\D  A non-digit: [^0-9]
\s  A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]
\S  A non-whitespace character: [^\s]
\w  A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]
\W  A non-word character: [^\w]
```

so you can use something like

```
System.out.println(s.matches("[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+"));
```

ps. this will match number such as 01.1 too. I just want to illustrate the \\.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `indexOf()` and `lastIndexOf()` :

```
int first = str.indexOf(".");
if ( (first >= 0) && (first - str.lastIndexOf(".")) == 0) {
    // only one decimal point
}
else {
    // no decimal point or more than one decimal point
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest

**Example:**

```
"123.45".split(".").length();
```

Comment: Digits check is not done. "abc.de" will work too in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count=0;
For(int i=0;i<mystring.length();i++){    
    if(mystring.charAt(i) == '/.') count++;
}
if(count!=1) return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below RegEx its solve your proble

1. allow 2 decimal places ( e.g 0.00 to 9.99)

   ```
   ^[0-9]{1}[.]{1}[0-9]{2}$

   This RegEx states:

   1. ^ means the string must start with this.
   2. [0-9] accept 0 to 9 digit.
   3. {1} number length is one.
   4. [.] accept next character dot.
   5. [0-9] accept 0 to 9 digit.
   6. {2} number length is one.
   ```
2. allow 1 decimal places ( e.g 0.0 to 9.9)

   ```
   ^[0-9]{1}[.]{1}[0-9]{1}$

   This RegEx states:

   1. ^ means the string must start with this.
   2. [0-9] accept 0 to 9 digit.
   3. {1} number length is one.
   4. [.] accept next character dot.
   5. [0-9] accept 0 to 9 digit.
   6. {1} number length is one.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I create myself to solve exactly question's problem.
I'll share you guys the regex:

`^(\d)*(\.)?([0-9]{1})?$`

Take a look at this [Online Regex](http://regexr.com/3eqpa) to see work properly

Refer documentation if you wish continue to custom the regex

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)